# How to delete elements in a list by index

Tags: python

[image]

I want to delete all code='A' records, below is my scripts, the problem is, when I delete record 1235, the 1236 will become to second row(before is third). so when i=3, 1236 will not be deleted, 1237 will be deleted. how to resolve it? Thanks in advance!

```
 for i in range(1,20):
     client=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody//tr["+str(i)+"]//td[@class='client_Name ng-binding'][1]").text
     code=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody//tr["+str(i)+"]//td[@class='ng-binding'][1]").text
     if client!='A':
         continue
     #delete action
     driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody//tr["+str(i)+"]//td[@name='Project']//i[@class='fa fa-trash']").click()
```

Comment: decrease i by one when you delete a row ?

Comment: do u know how to write the code？

Comment: what about i = i - 1

Comment: Details: 
Insert after delete action : 
   i = i - 1
This way, when a row is deleted the i will stay on the same line (which correspond to the next line before the deletion of the previous line).
That being said, the reverse iteration method is better.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over a list or array by incrementing an index *and* deleting elements is tricky because, as you have found, deleting elements changes the index of elements with higher indexes.

The solution is to iterate in reverse, by starting with the highest index and decrementing it.  This way deleting elements does not affect the indexes of the elements that have not yet been visited.

```
 for i in range(19, 0, -1):
     client=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody//tr["+str(i)+"]//td[@class='client_Name ng-binding'][1]").text
     code=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody//tr["+str(i)+"]//td[@class='ng-binding'][1]").text
     if client!='A':
         continue
     #delete action
     driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody//tr["+str(i)+"]//td[@name='Project']//i[@class='fa fa-trash']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a if condition you have to put, it is a while:

```
for i in range(1,20):
    client=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody//tr["+str(i)+"]//td[@class='client_Name ng-binding'][1]").text    
    code=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody//tr["+str(i)+"]//td[@class='ng-binding'][1]").text
    while client!='A':
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody//tr["+str(i)+"]//td[@name='Project']//i[@class='fa fa-trash']").click()
        client=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody//tr["+str(i)+"]//td[@class='client_Name ng-binding'][1]").text
```

It means that you loop on the same line until it is not an 'A', then you move forward.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your comments, but after use your scripts, it still cannot meet the requirement, for example, the table value for client, C/B/A/A/D.., the program will delete start from B.